# I need to print the values of the retrieved variables inside a div how do I do that?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a requirement where I need to display the details filled by the user before submit.I do not want to use ajax.I have tried retrieving the values using their ids but the values wont print inside the div and there are no syntactical errors shown in the browser console.

here is what I tried

```
<script>
document.onchange=function(){
var uname= document.querySelector('input[name="first_name"]').value;
var fhname=document.querySelector('input[name="father_husband_name"]').value;
var landline=document.querySelector('input[name="land_line"]').value;
document.getElementById("review").innerHTML="<h1>hello</h1><h2>"+uname+"</h2>";}
</script>
```

i need to print the values inside a div which is already created in the same page

Comment: youre missing the `<` in `<script>` at the first line

Comment: What happens when you use the browser's script debugger?  Is your `onchange` handler function invoked at all?  As you step through it, does each selector find the element you expect?  Does each variable get the value you expect?  Where specifically does this fail?

Comment: i tried using alert and it alerts all the values but it doesnt display

Comment: only hello is the output but when i use alert(uname) i get the value of uname as the alert

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that your code is correct. I assume that It looks something like this:

[image]

then output is:

[image]

console is clear and I think expected outcome is achieved... you can manipulate data before being posted to the server

if you have to alert value of selected checkbox you can use:

var own=document.querySelector('input[name="own"]:checked')
var isSelected = own == null ? false: own.checked
alert(isSelected)